# Printing users details which are in JSON format Like foreach in php

Tags: json, node.js

Since I'm new to NodeJS, I dont understand how to print all users and their details fettched from database which is in JSON format.

Like in PHP

```
foreach($users as $user){
   echo $user->user_name;
}
```

how to fetch user details one by one like above or any other way if the JSON data fetched from db is shown like below:

```
data = [{"uid":14,"name":"Sam"},{"uid":17,"name":"Sid"},{"uid":19,"name":"Saz"}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use normal for loop for the above task.

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  console.log("uid: "+data[i].uid+" name:"+ data[i].name)
}
```

The result will look like

```
uid: 14 name:Sam
uid: 17 name:Sid
uid: 19 name:Saz
```

Comment: Yes this is nice.. I got it.. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].uid)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `data` is an array, you can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
data.forEach(function (user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

The [Mozilla Javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) is a great source of standard Javascript documentation, which complement the [Node.js API reference](https://nodejs.org/api/) documentation.

I recommend to search and read in both sources when working with Node.

Comment: No its throwing an error:

forEach is not a function